# How to align QFormLayout in a QGroupBox by Horizontal center

Tags: c++, qt

I can`t understand how to align form layout in groupbox by center.

This is how i want it to work. (Correct)

[image]

This is how it works now. (Wrong)

[image]

Here is the code.

```
mainWinGroupBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Window Settings"));
mainWinGroupBox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
auto fWinLayout = new QFormLayout;
fWinLayout->setFormAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);

fWinLayout->addRow(tr("&Tray:"), trayCheckBox);
WindowWidthSB->setFixedSize(42, 20);
WindowWidthSB->setRange(0, 1920);
WindowWidthSB->setSingleStep(10);
fWinLayout->addRow(tr("&Window Width:"), WindowWidthSB);

WindowHeightSB->setFixedSize(42, 20);
WindowHeightSB->setRange(0, 1080);
WindowHeightSB->setSingleStep(10);
fWinLayout->addRow(tr("&Window Height:"), WindowHeightSB);

mainWinGroupBox->setLayout(fWinLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can align your labels with this property [QFormLayout::labelAlignment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformlayout.html#labelAlignment-prop).

Comment: Yes, but it`s only align the labels , but i want to align all the elements to center of the groupbox.

Comment: Sorry, I did not find how to achieve that. The size-policy of the labels does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Thank you for try, i also didn`t find that that`s why i asked here.